# What is the best approach to integrate plain JavaScript code in to angular app?

Tags: angularjs

I have a some plain javascript & css code which contains navigation/menu bar for a page. The goal is to integrate this into an angular application. Since the js code follows responsive layout and handles multiple events, I would prefer to avoid the complexity of converting that into angular code, moreover I would like to have the flexibility to replace just the js and css files if they are modified by a thid-party. Could someone point me to the best approach for integration?

Edit: I have created a directive and added a template to style as required using css classes. The issue I am facing is that the JavaScript events are not getting triggered. I even tried loading the template using the ng-include directive but the same result. The only way I got it to work was, when I put the entire template in the index.html file, instead of loading it as a directive. I have not integrated non-angular code earlier, so wanted to know if this would be the preferred approach?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? What your effort has been so far...list any resource you may have found.

Comment: One approach would be to use angular loader and requirejs. E.g., http://www.sitepoint.com/using-requirejs-angularjs-applications/ That way you can specify what script files get loaded and in what order.

Comment: Why can't you add your code to a directive? Question is too broad without more specifics